# How to custom related result Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I implement django rest framework and received bellow results:

```
{
    "count": 3,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "created_at": "2017-10-16T09:55:07.663791Z",
            "modified_at": "2017-10-16T09:55:07.663846Z",
            "visible": true,
            "name": "Viewer",
            "permissions": [
                2,
                3
            ]
        },
       ...
    ]
}
```

So I want field permissions would be:

```
 "permissions": [
    "name permission 1",
    "name permission 2"
 ]
```

What should I do?

Edited:

I add my models and serializer code:

Role:

```
class Role(BaseModel):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'role'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    module = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission,
                                     related_name='role_permission',
                                     through='RolePermission', )


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

RolePermission:

```
class RolePermission(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'role_permission'
        unique_together = (('role', 'permission'),)

    role = models.ForeignKey(Role)
    permission = models.ForeignKey(Permission)
```

RoleSerializer

```
class RoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: please, show models and serializer code

Comment: I added my code

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `RoleSerializer` to achieve this, along with a new serializer class for the `Permission` model.

```
class PermissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(object):
        model = Permission
        fields = ('name', )


class RoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    permissions = PermissionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields = '__all__'
```